# CKEditor with XPages showing only 1 line of HTML / DXL code

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I am not a web developer but have to keep running an existing XPages application which currently has the problem, that CKEditor displays only 1 row with HTML / DXL data. This issue may have to do with an updated version of Domino (and CKEditor) ...I cannot find the solution, tried to override the existing config.js file with no success. Would be great if the community could give me a hint where to start fixing ! Thank you !

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you undo your override of the CKEditor config.js as CKEditor in XPages is adapted to be used within XPages. So makre sure to use the standard XPages version of CKEditor and then let us know what then happens

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion ! In fact, I did the changes AFTER qute a time that the CKEditor is not working properly. So, my changes did not influence the behaviour of CKE. The currently installed version is absolutely Domino 10.0.1 FP 2 core stuff and has not been modified until today.

Comment: What error do you see with the standard XPages CKEditor?

Comment: I think that I have to try to make a simple XPage with a rich-element on it. If that works, I have to check elsewhere. Currently I am testing a on plugin-project with many styles AND a ckeditor config-file which may override the config.js on the server and may be the cause of the problems because outdated. In browser-debugger nor on the Domino console currently I am getting any error

Comment: Per Henrik, I just checked with a simple XPage containing a richtext-control: the CKEditor is being displayed perfectly like it should ! Thank you for let me think it over...so I will have to check the plugin now, the issue must be somewhere in it. Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard simple XPage containing a richtext control displays ok, my issue must be hidden somewhere in a self-developed plugin.